# qmap qt5 behaviour changed compare to qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5

Consider that example

```
QMap<int, int*> testMap;

auto middle = testMap.insert(512, nullptr);
auto left = middle - 1;
auto right = middle + 1;

if(left != testMap.end()) {
    qDebug() << "1 left key:" << left.key();
}
if(middle != testMap.end()) {
    qDebug() << "1 middle key:" << middle.key();
}
if(right != testMap.end()) {
    qDebug() << "1 right key:" << right.key();
}
```

When compiled with qt4.8.5 all works as excepted when qt5 is used (all with 4.8.1 on i686) left.key() gave me some headache ;]
Is there workaround about this behaviour?
thx

Comment: What is "auto left = middle - 1;" supposed to yield when your map only has one element?

Comment: Yes it should set iterator to end() as in qt4 and its not doing this in qt5.

Comment: From the qt documentation: "The iterator cannot check whether it reached the beginning of the map. Decrementing the iterator returned by begin() causes undefined results."

Comment: Can you point me to documenation? I only found this for java like iterators.

Comment: Take the quote, feed it to google.

Comment: This code is crashing for me with Qt 5, but getting this with Qt 4: 1 middle key: 512